# Orientation not changing on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation, orientation-changes

I have supported both LandscapeLeft and landscapeRight directions

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

But the orientation is not changing for landscapeRight. I have added observer to detect the orientation change events, those events are being called but the statusBar and navigation bar do not change for landscapeRight mode.

Comment: what is iOS version you are testing on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got TYPO
Instead of

```
UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight
```

you've got

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrei, Only this was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have checked it orientation support on your project setting.[image: Setting for project orientation support].

Comment: It is checked in project settings but not working :(